# Dynamically access struct value by field name in go template

Tags: go, go-templates

Is there a way to dynamically access a struct value by field name in go template?

For this code (https://play.golang.org/p/1B1sz0gnbAi):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type Context struct {
    Key string
}

func main() {
    var context = Context{Key: "value"}

    // Success
    var text = `{{ .Key }}`

    t := template.Must(template.New("success").Parse(text))
    _ = t.Execute(os.Stdout, context)

    fmt.Println("")
    
    // Fail
    text = `{{- $key := "Key" }}{{ .$key}}`
    t = template.Must(template.New("fail").Parse(text))
    err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, context)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("executing template:", err)
    }
}
```

I get this output:

```
value
panic: template: fail:1: unexpected bad character U+0024 '$' in command

goroutine 1 [running]:
text/template.Must(...)
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/text/template/helper.go:23
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox897259471/prog.go:26 +0x46b
```

I know how to do this for a map, I would just use index function. But that does not work for structs, and I do not have flexibility to change the underlying type passed in as context.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/RMmJunE26_j

Comment: IMHO: I'd rather use map than reflection. Map - simple, concise and clear. Reflection - needs more code and it's slow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even in regular golang code, accessing struct fields by name requires reflection, so it's not that easy in templates either. There is no built-in function allowing it, I am not aware of any library providing such function either. What you could do is implementing the function yourself. A very basic implementation could be as follows:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "text/template"
    "reflect"
)

type Context struct {
    Key string
}

func FieldByName(c Context, field string) string {
    ref := reflect.ValueOf(c)
    f := reflect.Indirect(ref).FieldByName(field)
    return string(f.String())
}

func main() {

    context := Context{Key: "value"}
    text := `{{- $key := "Key" }}{{ fieldByName . $key}}`
    
    // Custom function map
    funcMap := template.FuncMap{
        "fieldByName": FieldByName,
    }
    // Add custom functions using Funcs(funcMap)
    t := template.Must(template.New("fail").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(text))
    
    err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, context)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("executing template:", err)
    }
}
```

See it on the [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XYhGMNvdi4A)